# Country selction currency displays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three tables with specified fields/columns in braces:

```
Country (name,currency_id)
Currency (name)
User (name ,country_id,currency_id)
```

And my requirement is while creating user selecting upon country, default currency need to be display first and remaining currencies to be displayed in next selection row.
EX: if we select USA in country drop down in currency drop down USD need to be display first and remaining currencies in next

my idea is user belongs to any country default currency is his country currency and he has option to select other currencies also.

please help me out.

Comment: Do you want to the default currency to be selected or it should always be the first option?

Comment: it should always be the first option thanks

Comment: probably you need to write this in jquery. As if the user changes the country, the first option should be changed accordingly. Am I right?

Comment: yes same thing the first option should be changed accordingly

Comment: please give me the sujestion

Answer (score 0):

You know that user belongs to country and user belongs to currency.  You will also need country to belongs_to default_currency.

```
class Country
  belongs_to :default_currency, :class_name => "Currency"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, you have two select boxes in user form as:

```
<%= f.select :country_id, options_for_select(@countries.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id, {'data-currency'=>c.currency.id}] }), {}, :id => 'user_country' %>
<%= f.collection_select :currency_id, @currencies, :id, :name, {}, :id => 'user_currency'%>
```

where the country select will have options with an extra attribute `data-currency`, that can be used in jquery to find the correct currency option. The `@countries` and `@currencies` are:

```
@countries = Country.includes(:currency).all
@currencies = Currency.all
```

Now in jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#user_country').change(function(){
    var currency_id = $(this).find("option:selected").data('currency'); //collects the value of `data-currency` attribute of selected country.

    var currency_option = $('#user_currency').find("option[value='" + currency_id + "']"); //finds the option tag with the currency_id as value.
    $('#user_currency').prepend(currency_option); //prepends the currency_option to the currency select

    //the currency will be the first option now but it will not be selected by default
    //to make it selected replace the last line with
    //$('#user_currency').prepend(currency_option.attr('selected', 'selected'));
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

`User` doesn't need a `currency_id` because that can be derived from the `Country` that it belongs to. You can add a method to `User` to get back the currencies in the right order.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def ordered_currencies
    # Set up an array of currencies, with the default one first.
    default_currency = self.country.currency
    currencies = [default_currency.name]

    # Add in all other currencies except the default one.
    Currency.where("id != ?", defauly_currency.id).each do |currency|
      currencies << currency.name
    end

    return currencies
  end
  ...
end
```

In this case I made the method return back the names of the currencies, but if you want to return the `Currency` objects themselves you can change it easily.

Comment: He has clearly mentioned `user belongs to any country default currency is his country currency and he has option to select other currencies also`

Comment: I think there is some punctuation/words missing there. "User belongs to any country. The user's default currency is his country's currency."

Comment: Have you properly set up the associations using `belongs_to`, etc?

Comment: That's a bit backwards. `User` should have `belongs_to :country`, `Country` should have `belongs_to :currency` and `has_many :users`, and `Currency` should have `has_many :countries`. You can add some `through` ones too.

Comment: still iam getting undefined method `country' for #<Currency:0xa4c2278>

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `currency.country`. A currency has many countries, not just one. Please read more on Rails associations.